# Brace initialize tuple in function argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-functions

The main problem in question is that I want to write a function that takes two variable-length sets of arguments.

The abstraction I decided to go for is to emulate the following call syntax:

```
f({a,b,c},x,y);
```

If `a`, `b`, and `c` all have the same type, this can be made to work with

```
template <typename X, typename... A>
void f(std::initializer_list<X> xs, A&&... as) { . . . }
```

But a similar function definition with `std::tuple` instead of the `std::initializer_list` does not allow for my desired syntax.

```
template <typename... X, typename... A>
void f(const std::tuple<X...>& xs, A&&... as) { . . . }
```

Is there some trick I can use to allow the types in the first group to be heterogeneous?

Addendum: In general, I do not apriori know the size of `X...`.

Addendum 2: Does anyone know the technical reason why a braced initializer works for `std::tuple t{a,b,c}`, but not in the template argument context? Is it because in my example `xs` is not expanded by `X...`?

Comment: As an alternative, maybe you could use just a long list, and insert an otherwise unused type as 'separator'?

Comment: That's a decent suggestion, but I'd rather resign to `f(std::tuple{a,b,c},x,y);`.

Comment: @SU3 Be careful with `std::tuple{...}` though. The one-argument case might not behave as expected. `std::make_tuple` would be safer.

Comment: What do you mean with your second addendum? Your definition should accept the call you are showing.

Comment: @walnut But `std::tuple{std::tuple{'a'}}` would still have type `std::tuple<tuple<char>>`, would it not?

Comment: @SU3 It does not, that is the problem. `std::tuple{std::tuple{'a'}}` is deduced to `std::tuple<char>{std::tuple{'a'}}`.

Comment: @SU3 Sorry, actually in this case you probably want `std::forward_as_tuple`, not `std::make_tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is currently impossible with the syntax you want. The initializer list can only be deduced to an array or a `std::initializer_list`, both of homogeneous types.

This is a special rule. An initializer list has no type and simply cannot be deduced to anything else. If the function parameter is not an array or a `std::initializer_list`, then the parameter for which the initializer list was given becomes a *non-deduced context* and template argument deduction will ignore it.

In particular class template argument deduction cannot be done in a function parameter to determine the type from a braced initializer list as it can be done in a variable definition since C++17. Such a feature was not added to the language.

In principle you could allow a finite number of different types by using e.g. an array of `std::variant` as parameter, but that would be resolved to the type only at runtime and is unlikely to be what you want.

You need to either add a type name or function call to the initializer list braces as in

```
f(std::forward_as_tuple(a, b, c), x, y)
```

or you can use a tag type instead to indicate the end of the first pack in a flat argument list:

```
f(a, b, c, tag, x, y)
```

The tag can then be detected with some template work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is currently inconvenient, but there's another alternative to the one already provided:

```
f(a, b, c)(x)(y)();
```

If you exploit the fact, that `f` does not return anything, you can return a lambda or some other function object that accepts further arguments. An empty argument list could mean, that there will be no further arguments.

Example:

```
template <typename ...A>
auto f(A&& ...a)
{
  if constexpr (sizeof...(a) > 1)
  {
    std::tuple(std::forward<A>(a)...);
  }
  else
  {
     // burp
  }

  return [](auto&& ...a)
    {
      if constexpr (sizeof...(a))
      {
        return f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)...);
      }
      else
      {
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
      }
    };
}

int main()
{
  f(1, 2, 3)(4)(5)();

  return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/eAB2S4aCxxiSlMAF

EDIT: Try also this alternative:

```
template <typename ...A>
void f(std::any const(&)[3], A&&...)
{
}

int main()
{
  f({1, 2u, '3'}, 4., 5.f);

  return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/0OhoJpQ1YpSGOV2c

You can use a `std::variant` for type safety or something faster than what the STL provides. You can also write your own container, of course.

EDIT2: Then again:

```
template <typename ...A>
void f(std::initializer_list<std::any>, A&&...)
{
}

int main()
{
  f({1, 2u, '3'}, 4., 5.f);

  return 0;
}
```

Don't use `std::any`, of course, but your own fancy type.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/rqSVK6aj5zuSFRcf

EDIT3: There is yet another way:

```
class U
{
  void const* const v_;

  using typeid_t = void(*)();
  typeid_t const tid_;

public:
  template <typename T>
  static typeid_t type_id() noexcept
  {
    return typeid_t(U::type_id<T>);
  }

  template <typename A>
  U(A&& a) noexcept: v_(&a), tid_(type_id<std::remove_cvref_t<A>>()) {}

  template <typename A>
  A const& get() const noexcept { return *static_cast<A const*>(v_); }

  auto type_id() const noexcept { return tid_; }
};

template <typename... A>
void f(U const (&a)[3], A&&...)
{
  std::cout << a[0].get<double>() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  f({1.5, 2, 3.f}, 'a', 1);

  return 0;
}
```

You can make `typeid` checking optional and compile it only in the debug build.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/wgXOycB5I3bb3ExV

Comment: Now that I see this as a suggestion, after some time has passed, I think this might be a better option than I originally thought. Instead of `f(a, b, c)(x)(y)()`, `f(a,b,c)(x,y)` would be even better for my application (I only have 2 possible distinct sets of arguments). I'd just have to test if compilers can consistently optimize out the intermediate function object. I'd go with a function object instead of a lambda, so that copy and assignment operators can be deleted.

Comment: As you wish, here's an [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249308/deserializing-c-object-almost-automagically) in action.